# How do I check the record count after filtering with fat free framework?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I am using fatfree framework with the cortex ORM plugin. I am trying to get the number of records matching a specific criteria. My code:

```
$group_qry = new \models\system\UserGroup;
$group_qry->load(array('type=?',$name));
echo $group_qry->count(); //always returns 3, i.e total number of records in table
```

Initially I was thinking that this maybe because the filtering wasn't working and it always fetched everything, but that is not the case, cause I verified it with

```
while(!$group_qry->dry()){
    echo '<br/>'.$group_qry->type;
    $group_qry->next();
}
```

So how do I get the number of records actually loaded after filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this part is confusing: the `count()` method actually executes a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement. It takes the same arguments as the `load()` method, so in your case :

```
$group_qry->count(array('type=?',$name));
```

It is not exactly what you need, since it will execute a second `SELECT`, which will reduce performance.

What you need is to count the number of rows in the result array. Since this array is a protected variable, you'll need to create a dedicated function for that in the `UserGroup` class:

```
class UserGroup extends \DB\SQL\Mapper {
  function countResults() {
    return count($this->query);
  }
}
```

If you feel that it's a bit of overkill for such a simple need, you can [file a request](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/) to ask for the framework to handle it. Sounds like a reasonable demand.

#### UPDATE:

It's now part of the framework. So calling `$group_qry->loaded()` will return the number of loaded records.

Answer (score 0):

xfra35 is right, there was currently no method for just returning the loaded items, when using the mappers as active record. alternatively you can just count the collection:

```
$result = $group_qry->find(array('type=?',$name));
echo count($result); // gives you the number of all found results
```

in addition, i've just added the countResults method, like suggested. thx xfra35.

https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/commit/92fa18130892ab7d2303edc31d2b1f4bba70e881